# Dynamic (auto) page numbers are converted to static page numbers when exchanging files (Word 365 to Word 2019)

Tags: microsoft-word, troubleshooting, conversion, page-numbers

==== Update ===

I ran this test:

1. Viewed the file within my email. Page numbers are sequential as expected.
2. From within email, printed the file to a PDF. Page numbers are sequential as expected.
3. Downloaded the file, opened it, and clicked "Enable editing." Page numbers are now static and all pages have the number "2." The field code that controls auotmatic numbering is being replaced with a static, repetitive number.

I wonder if this might have something to do with my compatibility settings? In which case, I'm sort of lost on what to fix or the steps to do it. I need to be able to use Wor 2019 to work with files from 2010 to 365. There are no problems with the 2010 files. I do not have any 2013 or 2016 files to test.

==== Original Post ===
Here is what's happening:

- Joe uses Word 365 to create a file with dynamic page numbers and emails it to me.
- I open the file with Word Pro Plus 2019.
  All page numbers have been converted to the static number 2.

Notes

- There are NO section breaks in the file.
- I recently upgraded to Word 2019 from Word 2010.
- This was never a problem when I was using Word 2010. I.e., I could work with 2016, 2019, and 365 files without problems.

I tried searching online for a solution, but the hits are for "how to convert," even when I add keywords such as problem and troubleshoot.

Help?

Comment: I don't quite understand "dynamic page numbers" and  "static page number" in your questions. Are you talking about [Inserting Page Number Cross-References](https://word.tips.net/T000957_Inserting_Page_Number_Cross-References.html)? I perform the same operations according to that article. I get the static number 2 in my Word for Microsoft 365(Office 365) and Office Professional Plus 2019(VL).

Comment: @Herb Gu_MFST ~ By dynamic, I meant created with field codes so that page numbers would automatically update.  In a few moments I am updating the original post with new information based on test I just ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to turn off a Norton scriptcontrol for downloading documents. Details are at

[Solved (but lingering mysteries): 
Automatic page number converts to static when emailed file is opened with Word 2019](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2019/solved-but-lingering-mysteries-automatic-page/4a8e5c49-f1e6-418f-9859-e1e716558c72?tm=1591830322448)